# Is smarter software necessarily bigger?

Tags: design

This is kind of a vague question so I apologize in advance.

When software is "smarter", I tend to interpret that as really just saying that it covers more edge cases.  First of all, is this correct?

Assuming it is, does this mean that the software is full of if/switch statements to make sure input is handled properly, therefore making it "smarter"?

This thinking makes me feel like the code would end up bloated and messy.  I'm running into a point where I'm wanting to handle these edge cases, but I don't want to bloat my code merely overlooking some best practice. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know about your case, but in some cases, *not* covering edge cases means the software is *incorrect*. Simple as that.

Comment: Code examples would help here. "does this mean that the software is full of if/switch statements" -- no, usually not.

Comment: From my view there is not necessarily a correlation between size and smartness. I can think of any combination of the two aspects, and in fact I have seen more than once very smart solutions (from a user's viewpoint) done with very ugly code - they were/are so badly written that it is/was hard to maintain that mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When software is "smarter", I tend to interpret that as really just saying that it covers more edge cases. First of all, is this correct?

Sometimes, yes. Generally, not so much.

Consider a spell checker. A "smarter" spell checker might include suggestions for correction. It might get smarter yet to detect typos by transposed letters that are physically close on a keyboard. These don't check any extra edge cases, they do more work to provide better results.

> Assuming it is, does this mean that the software is full of if/switch statements to make sure input is handled properly, therefore making it "smarter"?

Very rarely. More often a different algorithm is used which solves "harder" variants of the problem or at least provides better results at the expense of "easy" problems or via time/resource consumption.

> I'm running into a point where I'm wanting to handle these edge cases, but I don't want to bloat my code merely overlooking some best practice.

Sometimes edge cases require this sort of conditional logic, but often they can be dealt with via a more general solution, or a more general view of your data.

It's not a guarantee that a solution for `A` and `B` is necessarily less complex than a solution for `A`, `B` *and* `C`.

Comment: +1: "More often a different algorithm ..." or architecture, or design pattern. For example, when I started with UI programming years ago, I had an incorrect understanding of event driven architecture. (Basically, I made direct function calls instead of posting messages. The resultant "behavior" is similar, but direct function calls usually burst into flames (infinite loops) in slightly more complicated "edge cases".) The articles on the comparison between Observer pattern and Publish-Subscribe pattern provide great insight into the choices, and ways to implement each properly.

Answer (score 6):

*`I would have written a shorter letter, but I did not have the time.`*
~ [Blaise Pascal](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal)

Smarter software is ***not*** necessarily bigger, but in most cases it is.

In the best case, smarter software simply doesn't allow you to follow an error path.  By controlling what conditions can occur, the total number of cases to be coded for can be reduced.

For example, three flags `A`, `B`, `C` provides up to 8 permutations.  If you only need 3 of those 8 permutations *and* the software prevents the other 5 from being selected, then you have written less code.  So the smarter application can be smaller.

But edge cases crop up all the time, and it can be difficult to control the permutations associated with those edge cases.  So the application needs more conditional checks and error path code.  In which case, smarter *does* mean bigger.

I opened my answer with Pascal's quote because it really captures the conundrum your questions presents.  If given the time, you'll have less code providing more functionality.  But that also requires or implies a solid understanding of the problem and the ability to find an eloquent solution.  Frequently, we run out of time to create the eloquent solution and our application codebase grows a proportionality larger amount as a result.

Answer (score 1):

As FrustratedWithFormsDesigner mentioned, more likely than not, not covering for edge cases produces incorrect or error prone software. Not to mention the security risks caused by poor handling of edge cases(i.e. buffer overflows, sql injection, etc.).

Intelligence of software depends on your definition, it may refer to software capable of machine learning, it may also refer to software that handles inputs & errors gracefully and goes the extra mile by doing the end user a favor. For example, suggesting links related to the search query when it returns no results. Autocomplete with suggested terms, etc...

Now, making your application "smarter" doesn't necessarily make it bloated or bigger. An efficient and well-written algorithm can probably keep your code from being bloated, not to mention that most of the times, there are already pre-existing libraries and frameworks out there that help you do the basics without bloating up your code.

For example, when dealing with sanitizing input from the user, instead of making a switch case block or a large if else block, a ruby on rails programmer can just make use of the [validates helper methods](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates). This drastically reduces the amount of code needed to do the form validations, not to mention that it makes your job easier.

In programming, there are always more than one way to do things, so if you think what you're doing is causing your codebase to bloat, take a step back and reexamine your code, maybe you can code it better to keep the bloat to a minimal.

Answer (score 1):

If the design is similar then yes it will be larger. No it shouldn't be bloated and messy.

Explore ways to handle your edge cases gracefully.  Contracts and aspect oriented programming are two such ideas you might find interesting.  Other than that smarter code organization can help.  Small functions that just check edge conditions and can be reused in multiple places can help cut down on clutter. Do you organize your code as precondition, work, postcondition?  I find that helps me keep things neat.

Also make sure your edge cases need to be handled. The fewer assumptions your code checks the more flexible it is when things change.  A function should only check things it needs to get the job done, unless it is "border guard" code that needs to do user input validation.

Answer (score -1):

No! smarter software can simplify how a problem is approached and solved, leaving fewer 'edge cases'. Less can be more.

Comment: Am I missing some nuance of the word smarter with my answer?